# How to pass return value from one `npm run script.js` as a parameter to another `npm run script2.js`?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Is there a way to implement it in `scripts` in `package.json` somehow without using third-party components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best solution but I couldn't come up with something better yet. Since I was looking for an approach for **Windows console** I've checked it only in there, but I think it should work in Linux shell too.

So, we will have 2 JavaScript files:

1. `send-param.js`: should send (return) a string param
2. `read-param.js`: should get that string param as an argument

Both these JS files should be run from scripts of `package.json`. The technique itself is pretty simple: the `send-param.js` writes a string value to `stdout` whereas `read-param.js` then gets it as an argument. The main problem was how to "convert" `stdout` into an argument for the `read-param.js` script.

To write something to `stdout` we can use `console.log` and that's what `send-param.js` actually does:

```
console.log("Hello World!");
```

Next, we want to run `read-param.js` to get the `"Hello World!"` string from arguments but it seems to be impossible to do it directly in Windows console. So I had to use an interim operation to write that argument from `stdout` to auxiliary file (I just named it `'1.txt'`) and here it's done in the first part of the script:

`node send-param.js > 1.txt`

Now we have `"Hello World!"` in the `'1.txt'` file and we have to send it somehow as a parameter the the `read-param.js` script. Again, I couldn't find how to do it directly in Windows console and used a variable which I called `'ARG'`:

`set /p ARG=<1.txt`

Finally, we can use the `'ARG'` variable as an argument for out `read-param.js` script:

"node read-param.js %ARG%"

The first thing that came to my mind was to execute all commands in one-line-script like this:

`"send-param.js > 1.txt && set /p ARG=<1.txt && node read-param.js %ARG%"`

but it wouldn't work since it's required to run `set` as a separate command ([see why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55238474/1844247)).

In `read-param.js` we just read the first argument as `process.argv[2]` (Node.js [reserves](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) the 0 and 1-st ones for its own arguments).

---

Here is the **final working example**:

*send-param.js:*

```
console.log("Hello World!");
```

*read-param.js:*

```
const argument = process.argv[2];

if (!argument)
    console.log('An argument is required.');
else
    console.log(`Argument: '${argument}'`);
```

*package.json:*

```
"scripts": {
  "send": "node send-param.js > 1.txt && set /p ARG=<1.txt && npm run read",
  "read": "node read-param.js %ARG%",
}
```

Now run the `npm run send` command and you will get: `Argument: 'Hello World!'`