# How to use Windows console 'set' variables with NPM scripts?

Tags: npm, cmd, package.json, npm-scripts

This works in Windows console as expected:

`set A="qwerty" && echo %A%`

the output: `"qwerty"`

But when I try to run the same commands in NPM scipts:

*package.json:*

```
"scripts": {
  "qwerty": "set A=\"qwerty\" && echo %A%"
}
```

`> npm run qwerty`

the output is: `%A%`

Am I doing something wrong or it just shouldn't work that way when run by NPM?

Comment: Well, your first command line does actually not work; do `set "A="`, then try it again, then you will get `%A%` echoed. To write *and* read a variable in the same line or block of code you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), so `set "A=qwerty" & echo(!A!` when having started the command prompt with `cmd /V:ON`. Alternatively, try `set "A=qwerty" & call echo(%^A%` (although this might still fail under some circumstances)...

Comment: Yes, my first command seemed to be working because of the previous run I guess.

Comment: Exactly, that is the reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example `set A="qwerty" && echo %A%` isn't correct. Variables in the `cmd` prompt / a batch file are expanded once per line / command:

```
==> set "A="

==> echo %A%
%A%

==> set A="qwerty" && echo %A%
%A%

==> echo %A%
"qwerty"
```

### [Why this behaviour?](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

> The `SET` command was first introduced with MS-DOS 2.0 in March 1983,
>   at that time memory and CPU were very limited and **the expansion of
>   variables once per line was enough**.

A workaround using the [`CALL` command](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html):

```
==> set "A="

==> echo %A%
%A%

==> set A="qwerty" && CALL echo %A%
"qwerty"
```

### Edit:

For the sake of completeness, the following batch script shows the mechanism of percent expansion and its combination with the `CALL` command **in detail** (note doubled `%` percent signs in the batch file `CALL Echo %%_var%%`):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
if NOT "%~1"=="" ECHO ON
echo        1st:
Set "_var=first"
Set "_var=second" & Echo %_var% & CALL Echo %%_var%%  
echo        2nd: 
Set "_var=first"
Set "_var=second" & CALL Echo %%_var%% & Echo %_var%
```

**Output, `echo OFF`:**

```
==> D:\bat\SO\55237418.bat
       1st:
first
second
       2nd:
second
first
```

**Output, `echo ON`:**

```
==> D:\bat\SO\55237418.bat on

==> echo        1st:
       1st:

==> Set "_var=first"

==> Set "_var=second"   & Echo first   & CALL Echo %_var%
first
second

==> echo        2nd:
       2nd:

==> Set "_var=first"

==> Set "_var=second"   & CALL Echo %_var%   & Echo first
second
first
```

Comment: I guess `set A="qwerty" && echo %A%` seemed to be working in my console because of the previous run which actually hadn't worked but I hadn't noticed that and saw only it working in the next runs.

Answer (score 1):

What I found so far is that these commands in order to work properly must be in different scripts and run in a specific order. So, here is the way how it works:

```
"scripts": {
  "aaa": "set TMP=test && npm run bbb",
  "bbb": "echo %TMP%"
}
```

`npm run aaa`

output:
`test`

But this one wouldn't work:

```
"scripts": {
  "aaa": "set TMP=test",
  "bbb": "npm run aaa && echo %TMP%"
}
```

`npm run bbb`

output: `<just empty>`

It looks like two separate `npm run` commands are required to find the created variable: the variable should be created in the first `npm run` and could be found in the second one.